# Data.Text parsers for Parsec 3.x

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm looking for a variant of Text.Parsec.Char.satisfy for Data.Text type or some polymorphic alternative, something with the following signature:

`satisfy :: Stream s m Text => (Text -> Bool) -> ParsecT s u m Text`

Succeeds for any Data.Text when supplied function (Text->Bool) returns True.

Did I miss such function or do I have to write it from scratch ?

Comment: Not sure this makes any sense. You're parsing a stream where each element is a `Text`? Or are you parsing a `Text` (in which case `Text.Parsec.Char.satisfy` should work fine)?

Comment: Out of curiosity I would like to parse `Text` with `Text` or `ByteString` with `ByteString` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have you somewhere imported `Text.Parsec.String`? Import `Text.Parsec.Text` instead. Then you can use the standard `satisfy`, as hammar says.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial combinator over `anyToken`: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:anyToken